# React-Redux: Unable to update price after quantity change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I creating a sale/order create screen.

Flow:
a)Product details is fetched from backend. b)Then quantity is selected and the data gets added to a table(tableData). tableData is used to addthedetails to one of the table. c)The total price and tax gets calculated.
Now when the quantity is changed the tax and total price has to be updated. That is where i am facing issues.

```
const SaleScreen = () =>{
    const [medicineName, setMedicineName] = useState('')
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState('')

    const productList = useSelector( state => state.productList )
    const { loading, error, products } = productList

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])
    const [dropDownData, setDropDownData] = useState(products)

    useEffect(()=>{
           setDropDownData(products)
        },[products])

    useEffect(() => {
         if(!userInfo){ navigate('/') }

        dispatch(listDoctors())
        dispatch(listProducts())
    },[dispatch, navigate, userInfo])

   //to add product and quantity to table data
    const addToTableHandler = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                const productToAdd = dropDownData.find((product) =>                product.medicineName.toLowerCase().indexOf(medicineName.toLowerCase()) > -1);
                let totalPrice = Number(addDecimals(productToAdd.mrp*quantity))

                const rowToAdd = {product: productToAdd, quantity: quantity, totalPrice: totalPrice};               
                setTableData(tableData => [...tableData, rowToAdd])
                
                const arr2 = dropDownData.filter((product) => 
                    product.medicineName.toLowerCase().indexOf(medicineName.toLowerCase()))             
                setDropDownData(arr2)               
                setQuantity('')     
    }

    //calcuation of the prices
        let itemTotalPrice = tableData.reduce((acc, row) => acc + (((row.product.tax/100) * row.totalPrice)+ row.totalPrice), 0).toFixed(2)
        let itemTotalPriceWithoutTax = tableData.reduce((acc, row) => acc + row.totalPrice, 0).toFixed(2)
        let totalGST = tableData.reduce((acc, row) => acc + ((row.product.tax/100) * row.totalPrice), 0).toFixed(2)
        let discountPrice = (Number(itemTotalPriceWithoutTax) - Number(itemTotalPriceWithoutTax*0.05)).toFixed(2)
        let saleTotal = (Number(discountPrice)+Number(totalGST)).toFixed(2)
        let totalQty = tableData.reduce((acc, row) => acc + Number(row.quantity), 0)

    //this is to change the quantity from the tableData
    const changeQuantity = (medicineName, quantity) => {
            const newArr = tableData.map(row => {
                  if (row.product.medicineName === medicineName) {
                        row.quantity = Number(quantity)
                      }
                  return row
                })
          setTableData(newArr)
        }

return (
        <>
        <h2>SaleScreen</h2>
        {
            loading ? <Loader />
                    : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
                    : ( 
                        <>
                 //this form is where product and quantity is selected and added to tableData
                        <Form onSubmit={addToTableHandler} >
                            <Row>
                                <Col md={6}>
                                    <Form.Group controlId='medicineName' >
                                        <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingSelect" label="Medicine">
                                            <Form.Control as='select' value={medicineName} className="mb-3"
                                                    onChange={(e) => setMedicineName(e.target.value)}
                                                    required
                                                    >
                                                    <option value=''>Select Medicine</option>
                                                    {dropDownData.map(product => (
                                                        <option key={product._id} value={product.medicineName}>{product.medicineName}</option>
                                                    ))  }
                                                </Form.Control>
                                            </FloatingLabel>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                </Col>
                                <Col md={5}>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId='quantity'>
                                        <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingInput" label="Quantity" >
                                            <Form.Control   type="number"  placeholder="Quantity"
                                                            value={quantity}
                                                            onChange = {(e)=> qtyCheck(e.target.value)}
                                                            required 
                                                            isInvalid={!!quantityErr}
                                                        />
                                        </FloatingLabel>
                                        {quantityErr.length>1 ? (<div className='errMsg'>{quantityErr}</div>): null}
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Col>
                                <Col md={1}>
                                    <Button type='submit' variant='primary'><i className='fas fa-plus'></i></Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Form>
                    
        
        //tableData is displayed in the below table and has the option to update quantity using changeQuantity function
                <Table striped bordered hover responsive='md' className='table-sm mt-3' id="table-to-xls">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>Sl</span></th>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>Medicine</span></th>
                                <th ><span className='btn'>Quantity</span></th>
                                <th><span className='btn'>Total</span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {   tableData.map((row) => (
                                        <tr key={row.product._id}>
                                            <td>{count++}</td>
                                            <td>{row.product.medicineName}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <InputGroup size="sm" className="mb-3">
                                                    <FormControl aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                                                        type='number' 
                                                        value={row.quantity}
                                                        onChange = {(e) => changeQuantity(row.product.medicineName,e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                 </InputGroup>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{row.totalPrice}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                ))

                                }
                        </tbody>                        
                </Table>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={9}>
              //below table displays the calculated data. 
                        <Table striped bordered hover responsive='md' className='table-sm mt-3' id="table-to-xls">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><span className='btn'>Total</span></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>Total Value</td>
                                    <td>{itemTotalPriceWithoutTax}</td>
                                    <td>Total CGST</td>
                                    <td>{totalSGST}</td>
                                    <td>Total SGST</td>
                                    <td>{totalSGST}</td>
                                    <td>{saleTotal}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>                        
                        </Table>
                    </Col>
```

I have removed the unimportant codes.

This might be work if the quantity state is changed, but in that case the when quantity state is changed, all the quantities in the table(tableData) also gets updated.
Is there anyway this can be achieved. Please let me know if you need any details. Sorry the code might not be a good one.

Comment: What is `tableData` and `setTableData`? Both appear to be undeclared in your snippet. It also appears that you are mutating the `tableData` in your handlers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for the response! Now i have made the code minimal and added comments to the code. Sorry I had missed adding the setTableData in the snippet.

Comment: Mutations and other comment(s) aside, I think for the price totaling it seems you are missing even using the row item quantity, i.e. something like `let itemTotalPrice = tableData.reduce((acc, row) => acc + (row.quantity * row.price) * (1 + (row.product.tax / 100)), 0).toFixed(2)`. The total is derived state, so it shouldn't be stored with the data, it should be computed from the data. Just update the item quantity and derive a computed total.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks a lot. I understand my mistake now. it worked!!